# Will listening to Galaxy Radio blow my stealth?

Tags: fallout-3

Or listening to any radio stations for that matter? The load-screen tips frequently mention turning off your pip-boy light, but never say a word about your radio.

Comment: No, but you'll keep asking yourself, haven't I heard this song already?

Comment: Of course, there are radio station expander mods that help with that for the PC version. My Galaxy News Radio has a 300-song playlist. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nope! Enemies only care about your footsteps, and how visible you are (which your pipboy's light affects).

Just think of the Lone Wanderer as having Pip-boy earbuds!

Comment: Wow, I'm sure I've read guides that said the opposite, guess that was back when it first came out and people were still going through the guts.